How to get actual version of bean with request scope from static version?
I have bean with request scope and I need to use it in static methods.
@Bean
@Scope(value = WebApplicationContext.SCOPE_REQUEST, proxyMode = ScopedProxyMode.TARGET_CLASS)
fun headerHolder(): HeaderHolder {
    return HeaderHolder()
}

I tried to use [ApplicationContextAware][1] interface for it but it did not help because spring calls setApplicationContext() method after creating ApplicationContext. But spring does not call this method if there was a new request and the bean with the request scope was updated. So it works only when an application starts. If I am mistaken, please, write about it.
@Component
class ApplicationContextProvider : ApplicationContextAware {

    override fun setApplicationContext(applicationContext: ApplicationContext) {
        context = applicationContext
    }

    companion object {
        private var context: ApplicationContext? = null

        fun getApplicationContext(): ApplicationContext = context
            ?: throw RuntimeException("Error getting ApplicationContext")
    }
}

But maybe there is some other way to access the ApplicationContext from a static method to get the current version of the bean with the request scope?

Nope, I don't think there's a better way, given the premise of the question. But, if a method needs access to a bean, it probably shouldn't be static, so sth doesn't sound right here design-wise
